# Sometimes cut image during PUT request

Tags: go

I have a function which uploads images to remote storage via PUT request

```
func sendFileToStorage(path string) error {
    logger.Get().Info(nil, "Got new file: " + path)
    request, err := newfileUploadRequest(path)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    fmt.Println(resp.StatusCode)
    return nil
}

func newfileUploadRequest(path string) (*http.Request, error) {
    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    url := config.Get().ExternalStorage.Url
    req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", url, bytes.NewBuffer(file))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    req.SetBasicAuth(config.Get().ExternalStorage.Login, config.Get().ExternalStorage.Password)
    return req, err
}
```

but sometimes the file uploads not completely. I mean the file can be cut. It happens when the image is big (more than 7mb).

When I try to upload the image with postman I don't have this problem. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does the request return any errors? And the status code is `200` (or `202`, whatever success code the API returns)?

Comment: request always returns 200

Comment: Yeah, don't know; your code looks fine as such. Maybe there's a difference in how postman handles certain network/HTTP conditions vs. Go? Unless I missed something in your code, this may not be an easy problem to figure out, and probably requires some in-depth digging.